# Puppet create windows user

Tags: ruby, windows, puppet

I am trying to create a new local Windows user using Puppet, the issue is that the documentation seems to show that the configuration options available in Puppet for Windows are not brilliant.

Does anyone have any better ways of doing this or a way of using Ruby to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#user-provider-features

For Windows you need to place the user in at least the `Users` group, set them to `managehome => true` for their profile to get created, and give them a password for them to be enabled (otherwise the account is disabled).

```
user {'bob':
    name      => 'bob',
    ensure    => present,
    groups    => ['Users','Administrators'],
    password  => 'plaintext_I_know_gross-use-hiera-or-blackbox',
    managehome => true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What configuration options are needed? When I have found that the puppet user resource is not sufficient I have used exec to run the windows 'net user' command to add a user.

Comment: The Net User command is fine, but it returns an error return code when used as the EXEC command from a Puppet manifest, which causes an alert in Puppet. I think I have found a way to do it in Ruby as a script, which means I can control the Return codes better